# Font Display issue

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.1

I am using Pidion phone with WM6.1.

When i set the regional language to thai (or other such as Vietnamese),
only icon label or text header are able to seen.
Button or text box all will turn to square box.
(Example clock and time show in little square box)

I google it, but most of the solution told to add font or install font cab file but it seem
useless.

Comment: Have you actually tried registering a font on the device that contains the glyphs you need?

Comment: No, i have a few window mobile phone, all of it working but not for this Pidion phone, i dont know how to paste the font into the square box.

Answer (score 0):

The fonts used are missong the thai glyphs. Just install a full unicode font (~20MB) or fonts that contain unicode thai glyphs.

Se here for how to get and test a font and it' unicode glyphs: http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2011/04/06/mobile-development-a-simple-unicode-character-map/

Comment: yes, is missing, i have try install different Unicode that consists thai glyphs but i still not appearing

Comment: Did you test the Unicoe Font with my CharMap tool? Unicode Fonts may be limitted in the number of code pages they support, which Windows TrueType Font did you install exactly on the device? Can you specify the char you are looking for in Unicode notation?